# My mac mini wont boot! is it my monitor or the mac?

Tags: mac

I just bought a old mac mini to start my ios dev. The mac mini has a DVI port, so I connected to my Dell 24" display which has a DVI connection. But my mac wont boot. Actually, I dont even know, if it is booting or not. Because my monitor did not show anything, as it did not get any signal and went to standby mode immediately. My questions are:

1. Do I have to connect keyboard and mouse to mini in order to boot?
2. Even I did not connect keyboard and mouse to mini, I will still see something on the monitor, won't I? something like a error message, telling me no any keyboard found. To make it clear, my display works fine with my PC.
3. I tried with my Microsoft USB keyboard and an IBM USB mouse. But I did not see any difference, i.e. nothing could be seen in the display.
4. Does it mean I have to buy keyboard and mouse from "Apple" to make it work.

Can someone help me and give me some hints. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Might be better posting here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry, I will post there.

Answer (score 0):

You should also at least hear the starting sound when you turn on your Mac Mini even if only the power is plugged in (the Mac mini has in-built speakers). So I'm afraid to say I think it's the Mac.

Comment: I think it is starting. But I cannot tell if it really started. Is it possible that the DVI port has some sort of problems?

Comment: Yea it's possible. You could try using the HDMI port with a HDMI-DVI adapter to see if you can get anything out of that.

Comment: unfortunately I dont have HDMI port on this mac mini. This one is a bit old and has only a DVI port.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of before taking it to an Apple store would be to try changing the DVI cable adapter if you're using one.

Comment: Thanks James. Just to be clear. Since the mac mini has a DVI-I port, I did not use any adapter. I used the DVI cable, came with the dell monitor. But the cable is a DVI-D, which is not exactly same as DVI-I. I am not sure, if it caused the problem. But as far as I understood, DVI-D cable can work with DVI-I port. Am I right? I am a bit confused, because not everyone is saying it is compatible.

Comment: Yea... I mean, it seems like a problem with the Mac from what you've said I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to connect a monitor in order for the mac mini to boot.

Yes, you should still see something on the monitor as you boot.

The mac mini actually should make the apple boot up sound that comes from the actual hardware when it successfully boots. If you don't hear that sound, either the mac mini has a borked speaker on the motherboard or it's damaged in some other way, but I'm betting on that it's damaged from your description of your issue.

Comment: I heard the mac is kinda running. But did not hear anything like an alarm.